# How to set an event listener callback to a member function

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm writing a small object-oriented wrapper around a canvas object, and I'd like to set some button callback to actual function members, instead of globally scoped functions (this way I can refer the context object as a member).

```
function CanvasManager(canvasId) {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);    
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');    

    var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
    imageLoader.addEventListener('change', this.handleImage, false);

    var lineNumberField  = document.getElementById('linenumber');
    lineNumberField.addEventListener('change', this.onLineNumberChange, false);
}

function handleImage = function(e) {
    var reader = new FileReader();    
    var that = this;

    reader.onload = function(event){
        var img = new Image();

        img.onload = function(){
            that.canvas.width = img.width;
            that.canvas.height = img.height;
            that.ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        };

        img.src = event.target.result;
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);     
};
```

This is called in an inline script in the html:

```
<div id="canvas-container" style="display:none;">
    <canvas id="imageCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
    ...
<script lang="javascript">new CanvasManager('imageCanvas');</script>
```

This doesn't work because in the `handleImage` callback, "this" doesn't refer to the `CanvasManager` instance, but the `imageLoader` instance, to my great confusion.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What `this` evaluates to generally depends on how the function is being called; but I don't see that in this code. Could you include that section?

Comment: Ah yes sorry, i'll edit

Comment: See [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

sorry for the comment - actually, I had misinterepreted the issue as you described it if the issue was inside the second method.

As the others implied, the event listener is going to call the function with `window` as the `this` object. Don't worry, even as a JS guru I agree it doesn't make a lot of sense.

While you can simply put everything in closures and put `this` into a constant `var` (ie, `me` or `self`) my preference is to customize the call to the function to always have a particular `this` reference. You can do this like so:

```
imageLoader.addEventListener('change', this.handleImage.bind(this), false);
```

bind() is a relatively new JavaScript function that gives you a new method, representing the original, but called with a particular `this` context. Some JavaScript libraries have equivalents that are compatible with older browsers, like Dojo's "hitch". But, since your code involves a `<canvas>` anyway, you should be mostly okay for compatibility.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind about bind (even though it is awesome) is that it doesn't work in IE8 and older. Though with the use of canvas this probably isn't an issue.

Comment: @David Yeah, you're already abandonding compatibility with Windows XP users; just like Microsoft already did.

Comment: +1 Yep. `bind` and its immediate-mode cousins `call` and `apply` have done wonders to simplify eventing and code reuse.  Off-topic: Microsoft has a hard time letting their products expire (because of their corp client base).  XP was great in its time. IE6 was great in its time (well...IE6 was OK).  But I'm glad MS is now a bit more forward looking. For example, they are now automatically pushing newer versions of IE during their nightly updates (farewell IE6-8)!

Comment: Ah thank you @Katana314, i kind of better get it now. And to hell with IE8 :)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
function CanvasManager(canvasId) {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);    
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');    

    var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
    imageLoader.addEventListener('change', this.handleImage, false);

    var lineNumberField  = document.getElementById('linenumber');
    lineNumberField.addEventListener('change', this.onLineNumberChange, false);
    var self = this; // keep CanvasManager instance
    this.onLineNumberChange  = function(){
    };
    this.handleImage  = function(){
       console.log(self); // use CanvasManager instance
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your function handleImage is outside your main function (or class) that you are trying to use. I would update the code as below:

```
function CanvasManager(canvasId) {
    var me = this;

    me.canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);    
    me.ctx = me.canvas.getContext('2d');    

    var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
    imageLoader.addEventListener('change', me.handleImage, false);

    var lineNumberField  = document.getElementById('linenumber');
    lineNumberField.addEventListener('change', me.onLineNumberChange, false);

    me.handleImage = function(e) {
        var reader = new FileReader();    

        reader.onload = function(event){
            var img = new Image();

            img.onload = function(){
                me.canvas.width = img.width;
                me.canvas.height = img.height;
                me.ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            };

            img.src = event.target.result;
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);     
    }
}
```

By moving the handleImage inside the function it is now in scope of the class. Also by using me = this at the start of the method to always have access to it's class instance as the this will by default reference the objects who's event triggered it.